# Adding items to a list in XAML C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Well I have a class Employee. In this class I have a property

```
public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
```

The project class looks like this:

```
   public class Project
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }
```

Now I want to add to an employee a list with projects in the xaml:

```
 <models:Employee Firstname="Jane" Lastname="Doe">
                <models:Employee.Projects>
                    <models:Project Id="1" Name="Abc"></models:Project>
                </models:Employee.Projects>
            </models:Employee>
```

Now the models:Employee.Project gets underlined and if I hover over I get the error:

```
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')
```

Comment: Where is your class Employee?

Comment: What is the type of your project? Could you provide a [reproduce demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?